# Chinese reminder theorem Vs Sylow

Tags: abstract-algebra

Bonjour everyone!
I wanna know the difference between Chinese Remainder Theorem and p-Sylow's subgroup "factorization". Is there a way to use one for the proof of the other. Thanks.

Comment: What should be the connection, apart that they are both true?

Comment: Instead of being both true, there's nothing else that can link these two theorem?

Comment: I am not even sure what you mean by "factorization" in connection with Sylow subgroups. But the only connection I can see is the pretty trivial statement that a cyclic group has a unique Sylow subgroup for each prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the factorization using Sylow's theorems is the one that if $G$ has a normal sylow for all primes dividing the order of $G$, then $G$ is a direct sum of its (unique) normal Sylows.

This bears little resemblance to the CRT for the following reasons:

1. It's for finite groups, but the CRT applies to rings, even infinite ones.
2. It means the factors will always be of prime order, which is not necessarily the case for the CRT

I guess you may have been fooled into thinking there was a connection since it seems to work well for $\mathbb Z_n$. There it is true that the Sylow factorization as a group amounts to the same thing as viewing it as a ring and splitting it up along its prime-power components. But this is a rather narrow, nice case that doesn't generalize.